# Use sh404SEF router from a plugin

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7, joomla2.5

I'm developing a Joomla 2.5 content plugin that need to programatically create a SEF url when an article is saved.

I've managed to make this work when the regular Joomla SEF is activated. My plugin is using the regular Joomla JRoute::_(); to build a SEF URL. This works great with native Joomla.
For example the url

```
http://localhost/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=123
```

is translated to

```
http://localhost/index.php/mycategory/article-title-123.html
```

My code looks like this:

```
private function joomlaSefUrl($article){
        require_once(JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_content'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'route.php');
        $siteURL = substr(JURI::root(), 0, -1);
        if(JPATH_BASE == JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR) {
            // In the back end we need to set the application to the site app instead
            JFactory::$application = JApplication::getInstance('site');
        }
        $articleRoute = JRoute::_( ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->id, $article->catid) );
        $sefURI = str_replace(JURI::base(true), '', $articleRoute);
        if(JPATH_BASE == JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR) {
            $siteURL = str_replace($siteURL.DS.'administrator', '', $siteURL);
            JFactory::$application = JApplication::getInstance('administrator');
        }
        $sefURL = $siteURL.$sefURI;
        return $sefURL;
    }
```

The problem is that when third party extensions like sh404SEF is installed the SEF URL that I get from using the JRoute::_() method is still the the regular Joomla route url:

```
http://localhost/index.php/mycategory/article-123.html
```

instead of the expected sh404SEF's url

```
http://localhost/Mycategory/article-title.html
```

Joomla doesn't see that the sh404SEF is installed, so by using the JRoute::*(), I allways get the regular SEF Joomla url. So I need to find a way to use the sh404SEF JRoute::*() class directly from within my plugin, instead of the regular Joomla router class.

Does anyone know how the sh404SEF classes work?

Answer (score 0):

With Joomla! to get rid of the `index.php` section of the URL you need to turn on `mod_rewrite` in you global preferences and enable the `.htaccess` file that comes with the basic install. (When you first install Joomla! it's called `htaccess.txt` duplicate and rename the copy to `.htaccess`

For more complete information read this on [Joomla Docs about SEF URLs](http://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs).

You could try looking at the source of the [sh404SEF plugins on JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/sh404sef-extensions)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the question. Im looking for a way to use the sh404SEF router classes from within a plugin, and not how to get SEF urls in Joomla.

Comment: Sorry I was confused by two examples you gave one with the index.php in the URL and the other without. The only way to get rid of that part is with mod_rewrite + .htaccess. Even sh404SEF needs that.

Comment: No problem. Yes I know that you need the .htaccess, which I also have. But the question is still how to access and use the sh404SEF classes and routers programatically from a plugin. When you use the JRoute::_() class methods of Joomla, the class doesn't care if sh404SEF is installed. So how do you use the sh404SEF's JRoute::_() method instead.

Comment: It's been a while since we've added support for sh404SEF to any of our components but you could try reading the source of the sh404SEF plugins on JED http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/sh404sef-extensions

Comment: That's a great tip. I think I have to start there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use function getSefFromNonSef in file

> administrator\components\com_sh404sef\helpers\general.php

Example:

```
$url = 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1:aaaaaaaaa&catid=2&Itemid=101'
$sef_url = Sh404sefHelperGeneral::getSefFromNonSef($url, true, false, null);
```

Remember, non-sef url, starting with index.php?...